# Leverage Browser Caching Not Working in htaccess of PHP project

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, caching, seo

I added following code in .htaccess file of my php project.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
```

But still google analyzer is not marking it as resolved. it is showing (expiration not specified) for every image,css and js.
Do I need to do something else to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration seem good.

mod_expires is enable in your apache configuration ?

can you provide the result of :

```
curl -I http://yourdomain/an_asset.jpg
```

EDIT :
I add a non exhaustive list

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "now"
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 5 minutes"
    ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 5 minutes"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 30 days"
    ExpiresByType application/mac-binhex40 "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType application/msword "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType application/octet-stream "access plus 30 days"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType application/x-cdf "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType application/x-director "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 30 days"
    ExpiresByType application/x-netcdf "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 5 minutes"
    ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 5 minutes"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType application/zip "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 30 days"
    ExpiresByType audio/basic "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType audio/mpeg "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType audio/x-aiff "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType audio/x-wav "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType image/bmp "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 30 days"
    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 7 days"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 30 days"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 5 minutes"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 30 days"
    ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 5 minutes"
    ExpiresByType video/quicktime "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 365 days"
    ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 365 days"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 365 days"
    ExpiresByType video/x-msvideo "access plus 1 day"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanx, Can you please tell me how to check mod_expires at my end as I am not the server admin.

Comment: thanx, after mod_expires enabled, it started working but not for .js files. is there something wrong for .js files?

Comment: add this `ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"`

Comment: and this `ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 30 days"`

Answer (score 0):

[compress-php-css-js-javascript-optimize-website-performance](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/compress-php-css-js-javascript-optimize-website-performance/)

Just replace "/the/full/path/of/this/file" path to your correct directory by using this php code `dirname(__FILE__)`